# what does ^ mean in bool GetDeviceInformation(String ^ port, LibCECConfiguration ^configuration, uint32_t timeoutMs)

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I came across this function with arguments like this. I am wondering what does the ^ mean in here.

```
bool GetDeviceInformation(String ^ port, LibCECConfiguration ^configuration, uint32_t timeoutMs){}
```

Cheers,
Lan

Answer (score 3):

That a C++/CLI "reference". In particular, this is **not** C++ but a Microsoft extension to it. In C++, the caret is always the XOR operator.

Comment: Hats are also used for reference-counted pointers in C++/CX.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CLI (common language interface) reference; used in Microsoft's managed C++ environment. They have similarities to pointers. (You need to program in C++ CLI if, for example, you're building an interop layer between C++ and C#).

It is not standard: in standard C++, ^ is the eXclusive-OR operator.